# How to improve dpi/resolution pdfkit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

Currently using pdfkit, for the most part it's been great to use.

The only issue is line thickness.  Borders on the source html look great, on the pdf generated look much thicker.

Also thickness varies in the document.  On lines of the same width, it appears thicker in places.  Even borders on the same div may appear thicker on the 3 of the 4 borders, even though they have the same CSS.

Any way to remedy this?

Answer (score 0):

Well if you explore the extended help `-H` on `wkhtmltopdf` you would find a options called dpi

So perhaps you can set a `dpi` in pdfkit something like this

```
PDFKit.configure do |config|
  config.wkhtmltopdf = '/path/to/wkhtmltopdf'
  config.default_options = {
    :page_size => 'Legal',
    :print_media_type => true,
    :dpi => [your dpi setting]

  }
  # Use only if your external hostname is unavailable on the server.
  config.root_url = "http://localhost" 
end
```

### Note

Having said that it you examine the help deeply you would know that that it states

```
-d, --dpi <dpi>                     Change the dpi explicitly (this has no
                                      effect on X11 based systems)
```

I clearly state it has no effect on system that based on `X11` so I would rather see that of any help for you

### Other options

So dpi options is hardly of use what are other options ?

Well in fact there is one  check this [link](https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/issues/detail?id=229) and trace to last comment and see some of that help in your quest (i.e try increasing the resolution of the xvfb in case if your running an xvfb server)

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried the dpi setting but it seems to have no effect.  I don't have xvfb installed, but that's an interesting idea I will have to investigate more.